# Eclipse won't autocomplete when instantiating a class with Codeigniter

Tags: php, eclipse, codeigniter, autocomplete

When I try to instantiate my class with Codeigniter, Eclipse won't show my methods on auto completion.

This is the way I am trying it:

```
$this->load->model('myclass');
$this->myclass-> // This shows nothing
```

But when I use the classic way of php to instantiate my class, the auto completion shows all methods and everything.

```
$this->load->model('myclass');
$myclass = new myclass();
$myclass-> // This shows all methods
```

How can I make Eclipse to autocomplete when I type `$this->myclass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't support autocomplete extension for framework level like codeigniter. It only supports for language level like php. So, you need to add your own. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794491/code-igniter-2-1-autocomplete-intelisense-in-eclipse#14802052) will be useful for you.

This is not directly related for your question. But I recommend to use [Sublimetext](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) and it is lightweight and has tons of [code snippet](https://packagecontrol.io/) for not only modern framework like [Codeigniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/) and [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) but also frontend framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and [Angularjs](https://angularjs.org/) .

Hope this answer will be useful for you.